# How to Construct Spatio Temporal Clusters of Time Series Data in R

Tags: r, clustering, hot-spot

I have count data of one disease for various districts of a state of India on monthly basis. Is it possible to draw spatio temporal clusters in R? I have checked some R- packages for example `surveillance` and got a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0416v1.pdf) which states a model 'hhh4' in Section 5 which nearly talks about my problem. But I am not good at data objects of various geographical classes. Is there any way from which I can use my csv file (which contains months, case count and lon lat) and analyse significant clusters over time (in R, secondarily ArcGis)?

Answer (score 1):

The "endemic-epidemic" modelling framework `hhh4` in **surveillance** focusses on parameter inference (e.g., epidemic proportion) and short-term forecasts for (multivariate) count time series, see the corresponding [`vignette("hhh4_spacetime")`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/web/packages/surveillance/vignettes/hhh4_spacetime.pdf).
The package does contain tools for outbreak detection but these are limited to *univariate* count time series and categorical time series, see the [`vignette("monitoringCounts")`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/web/packages/surveillance/vignettes/monitoringCounts.pdf).

For *space-time anomaly detection* in R you have to resort to another package:

**scanstatistics** - https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=scanstatistics

It contains an [introductory vignette](https://CRAN.R-project.org/web/packages/scanstatistics/vignettes/introduction.html), which explains and exemplifies how to apply different scan statistics based on a dataset of counts by region and time period and a dataset of corresponding spatial coordinates, such as provided by your csv file.